# looping through page number links with selenium issue

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I’m working with selenium and beautiful soup, in python 3.6.  I’m trying to click the listed pages in the footer or a page.  Each time I click the number in the footer it takes me to the next page.  I then scrape some data from an element and added it to a list.  Everything works fine with the code below until I hit 8 where the next span just contains ‘…’ instead of a number.  You have to click on the ‘…’ and then adds a few more numbers to the page footer.  Any tips on how to deal with this would be greatly appreciated.

code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

emptLst=[item['href'] for item in soup.select('a.job-card-search__link-wrapper')]

for i in range(int(round(503/14))):

    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[aria-label="Page '+str(i+1)+'"]').click()

    LnkLst = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('a.job-card-search__link-wrapper')]

    emptLst+LnkLst


    time.sleep(3)
```

page source:

```
<section class="search-results-pagination-section">
                      <artdeco-pagination class="artdeco-pagination    pv5">
<!---->
    <ul class="artdeco-pagination__pages artdeco-pagination__pages--number">
          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number active selected">
    <span>1</span>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 2" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-255="255">
      <span>2</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 3" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-258="258">
      <span>3</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 4" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-261="261">
      <span>4</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 5" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-264="264">
      <span>5</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 6" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-267="267">
      <span>6</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 7" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-270="270">
      <span>7</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 8" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-273="273">
      <span>8</span>
    </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number">
  <button data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-276="276" data-is-animating-click="true">
    <span>…</span>
  </button>
</li>

          <li class="artdeco-pagination__indicator artdeco-pagination__indicator--number ">
    <button aria-label="Page 23" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-279="279">
      <span>23</span>
    </button>
</li>

    </ul>

<!----></artdeco-pagination>


                    </section>
```

Comment: Can you share the url? Answer given below could be an approach. Usually when you near the ellipsis (...)  the numbering updates on the pagination so you may need to account for that. If there is a next button you could click that until you reach the known  number of pages.

Answer (score 0):

If possible I would suggest constructing the URLS for new pages by hand. A lot of websites will simply change an additional parameter in the url for page numbers.

For example, we could look at the urban outfitters website. Normal clothing sections are paged, with the first page url looking something like (I'm looking at the sale category here):

https://www.urbanoutfitters.com/sale

If I look at the url for the 2nd page of sale items I see that they just add an extra argument in the url:

https://www.urbanoutfitters.com/sale?page=2

and this continues similarly for any other pages beyond the first. I've run into a similar issue as what you're dealing with and found this approach much easier and less prone to error.